# Can I upgrade to Mountain Lion from Snow Leopard?

Tags: snow-leopard, upgrade, macos

I'm currently running Snow Leopard (10.6.8) and I never upgraded to Lion.

However, the features in Mountain Lion have me intrigued and I'd like to upgrade.

Am I allowed to upgrade straight to Mountain Lion from Snow Leopard, or do I need to somehow upgrade to Lion first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. As long as you're running the most up-to-date Snow Leopard version (10.6.8), you can directly upgrade to Mountain Lion, as detailed on [Apple's 10.8 Upgrade Page](http://www.apple.com/osx/how-to-upgrade/). Just download from the App Store and you should be good to go.

Comment: Excellent! I'm still pretty new to the OSX ecosystem, so I wanted to make sure.